# How to fix 'obscured' error in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

On a non-public webpage I have the following html content:

```
<span click.delegate="placeCurrentInjection()" style="display:flex" class="au-target" au-target-id="611"> 
<ui-button glyph="glyph-iclamp" small="" primary="" disabled.bind="currentPlaceDisabled" 
style="width: auto; max-width: 20em;" class="au-target ui-small ui-button primary" au-target-id="612" role="button" data-value="">
    <span class="ui-indicator"><!--anchor--></span>
    <ui-glyph glyph.bind="glyph" class="au-target ui-icon ui-btn-icon glyph-iclamp" au-target-id="36"><!--view-->
    <svg>
      <use tabindex="-1" x="0" y="0" class="au-target" 
      au-target-id="11" xlink:href="#glyph-iclamp"></use>
    </svg>
    <!--anchor--></ui-glyph><!--anchor-->
    <!--anchor-->
    <span class="ui-label">Place current injection<!--slot--></span>
    <!--anchor--></ui-button> </span>
```

which shows a button like follows:

[image]

and I want to click on that button, using the following code in selenium 3.8.0:

```
elem = WebDriverWait(self.webdriver, time_sec).\
                until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Place current injection')]")))
elem.click()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
E       ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <span class="ui-label"> is not clickable at point (782.2999877929688,156.03334045410156) because another element <ui-button class="au-target ui-small ui-button primary"> obscures it
```

Despite the fact the actual text is not obscured in any way and I can click on it - how to fix this issue?

Comment: Check, if there is only one element with this xpath: `//span[contains(text(), 'Place current injection')]` in whole document. If it is only one, try to do some debugging, what can be that obscuring element `<ui-button class="au-target ui-small ui-button primary">` and try to use `is_visible()` and `is_displayed()` methods.

Comment: Error message is clear, you have to click the _element <ui-button class="au-target ui-small ui-button primary">_

Comment: @DebanjanB: But this is confusing: I want to click on the element with the text "Place current injection". But to do that, I have to click on something else? That actually does not make sense and is not intuitive...

Comment: @DebanjanB: Also I have to find that element by looking for the classes, which I think is not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you located is just the text on a label of the button. You need to click on the button itself, which is actually the element from the error message you received. The button is the parent element so you can use the text to locate it by moving to the parent

```
(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Place current injection')]/..")
```